# Momentum and its conservation

Tags: kinematics, rotational-kinematics

[image]

Which is correct  answer? How can I understand when which momentum will be conserved or not?

Comment: I have same doubt..

Comment: Yes it is multi correct question..

Comment: @XcoderX the question has asked which of the following ARE not true. This question has multiple answers.

Comment: I see key for question and found the answer. It is c. C is wrong. But how ?

Comment: https://www.britannica.com/science/conservation-law#ref5520 should answer your query

Comment: Angular momentum can only be conserved when linear momentum is conserved

Comment: Duplicate? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/163683/is-momentum-conserved-in-the-collision-of-a-ball-with-a-hanging-rod

Comment: @Farcher this problem also involves angular momentum, so it can be said to be an extension, but not duplicate

Comment: @XcoderX , angular momentum can remain conserved even when linear momentum is not conserved.

Comment: but logically linear momentum is the momentum of the system, and then shouldnt it be conserved if angular momentum is conserved?

Comment: Not necessarily. This case is a exception. If the rod were not pivoted at a point, both the momentum terms would be conserved. But for the rod+particle system, the reaction at the pivoted point is an external force, which changes the liner momentum.

Comment: @srivishnu You must be reading the answer key wrong. A, B and D cannot be true at the same time. They are contradicting.

Comment: @Steeven , They all (A,B,D) are the answers, the question is asking the false options.

Comment: I see. Sorry, I misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that all conservation laws **always are valid**. Energy is always conserved, momentum is always conserved, angular momentum is always conserved etc. If they are not valid, then we are not including the whole system.

For example, energy is of course not conserved if we allow energy to leave the system and to be absorbed by something external. Same for momentum and angular momentum.

Is momentum or angular momentum transferred out of the system in any way? This can only happen if there is some external force acting in the case of momentum or some external torque in the case of angular momentum.

So the question boils down to that: *Are there external forces or torques present?* Try to see if the problem can be solved through such consideration.