# Is the Momentum conserved?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, momentum, collision

I was trying to solve a simple problem regarding a particle being launched by an angle theta where it hits a rod, we have:
a) System(Particle, Rod)
b) System(Particle, Rod, Henge)

My question is when will the angular momentum in each of the systems is conserved and is the linear momentum in any system conserved? And why?

I'm taking this course online, so if anybody could give me a rigorous and an intuitive explanation of what's going on it eould really mean alot to me.
Thank you alot for your time
Image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtP84.jpg

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is momentum conserved in the collision of a ball with a hanging rod?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/163683/)

Comment: @sammygerbil i saw this, but why would the henge exert a force on the Rod? Is it always thw case or is it due to collision and why it's direction upward, thank u

Comment: Without the hinge the rod will move away after being struck by the ball. The hinge exerts a force on the rod to prevent the fixed end from moving away. If the CM of the rod rotates around the hinge a centripetal force is required.

Comment: @sammygerbil so during contact the rod will exert a force F on the particle while the particle would exert another force on the rod, these will cancel each other, however the henge is exerting a force F upward on the rod and so the rod will stay stayionary and not moving atfter this, but rotation will take place in the clockwise direction, is this right?

Comment: The impact is sudden so the force is best described as an impulse. The force of A on B does not cancel the equal and opposite force of B on A because they act on different objects. The ball will rebound (unless it sticks to the rod) and the rod will rotate clockwise about the hinge. Study similar examples in online tutorials : eg google "physics ball collides with hinged rod". Khan Academy is quite good. (The online course you are taking ought to explain what is happening. If not then find a better course.)